# Batch to move files outside of randomly-named subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, file-rename

I have a data set consisting of files organised according to the following hierarchical folder/subfolder structure:

[image]

I would like to remove all nuisance subfolders (move its contents outside of it at the same hierarchical level + delete the nuisance folder), thus ending up with the files organised like this:
[image]

How can I achieve this, using a batch file, run from a command prompt inside Windows 7? I've tried a number of for statements with %F and %%F, but none worked. Grateful for any tips.

Comment: Without any hint how to distinguish nuisance from useful neither file nor folder this task is unsolvable.

Comment: You have a potential major problem with your goal. The great-grand-child folder names may collide when you attempt to move them to the "person n" level. You can run into the same problem with file names if each useful folder may have multiple child folders.

Comment: @LotPings Sorry if I was unclear. I tried indicating in the hierarchies above which subfolders are the nuisance ones. Those are the two subfolders immediately under the person parent folders; and the subfolder that immediately contains the useful files.

Comment: @dbenham You are right. I forgot to mention though that all those random file and (sub)folder names are in fact all unique, so the overwrite is not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following will accomplish your goal ***if and only if all child folder and file names are unique***. If there are duplicates, then all hell will break loose.

I have not tested, so backup and/or try the code on disposable data first.

You will have to modify the first PUSHD command to point to the root where all your "person n" folders reside.

```
@echo off
pushd "yourRootWherePersonFoldersReside"
for /d %%U in (*) do (
  pushd "%%U"
  for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /ad 2^>nul') do (
    for /d %%B in ("%%A\*") do (
      for /d %%C in ("%%B\*") do (
        md "%%~nxC"
        for /d %%D in ("%%C\*") do move "%%D\*" "%%~nxC" >nul 2>nul
      )
    )
    rd /s /q "%%A"
  )
  popd
)
popd
```

The second FOR loop must be FOR /F instead of FOR /D because FOR /D has the potential to iterate folders that have been added after the loop has begun. FOR /F will cache the entire result of the DIR command before iteration begins, so the newly created folders are guaranteed not to interfere.

Comment: Thanks. This is very close to achieving the goal. The only problem is, the files are moved at the same level as the folders that should in fact contain them (what I termed "useful folder x of N"). Like this: https://snag.gy/HFawxS.jpg

Comment: Oh, and actually I realise that these useful folder names (the ones immediately containing the files) are in fact the same across persons. But that should not be a problem, as each of them resides within the person's folder.

Comment: Unfortunately I am completely unversed in this scripting language so cannot make the probably trivial change to your code that changes the behaviour. Or if it's easier, perhaps you could add some short comments to your code so I can debug it myself. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @z8080 - The MOVE command had the wrong target location of `.` (current directory), when it should have been the same location as the MD (make directory). All fixed.